# SVD or Cholesky on sum of SPD matrices

Tags: symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, svd, cholesky-decomposition

Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrices and $C=A+B$. I know the SVD or Cholesky decomposition of A and B, $A=U_A\Sigma_AU_A^T=L_AL_A^T$ and $B=U_B\Sigma_BU_B^T=L_BL_B^T$.

Can I use the factors from $A$ and $B$ to directly compute the SVD or Cholesky decomposition of $C$? Or do I have to compute $C=A+B$ and then do either SVD or Cholesky on $C$ directly?

This is relatable to [QR decomposition or SVD of the sum of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4185515/qr-decomposition-or-svd-of-the-sum-of-matrices), but in my case $A$ and $B$ are SPD.